# Losing HTML escapes after conversion to string

Tags: java, android, html, dom

This code was tested with Android:

```
    public static void test() {
        String text="<html>" +
        "<head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\" />" +
        "<title>Testing Escapes with DOM</title>" +
        "</head>" +
        "<body lang=\"en\"><p>This is an escape: &mdash;</p></body>" +
        "</html>";

        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document inputDoc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes()));

            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(inputDoc), new StreamResult(baos));

            System.out.println("Result: " + baos.toString());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
Result: <html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Testing Escapes with DOM</title>
</head>
<body lang="en">
<p>This is an escape: </p>
</body>
</html>
```

(The actual code doesn't just copy input to output, but has some filtering)

The question is about **&mdash;** which is present in the original text, but didn't appear in the output.

When I look into the document created after parsing, it actually has an EntityReference node for &mdash;
but it looks like DOMSource wants any Entity to be resolved and skips it otherwise.

Unlike XML, HTML does not accept ENTITY, therefore predefined entities are the only ones which are recognised.
For that reason I just want all entities to appear in the output "as is" without being resolved.  Is there a way to do that? (Maybe an alternative to DOMSource + Transformer?)

Of course I can replace all escapes with actual utf characters, and this will certainly work.
But my text has numerous escapes, and it will be a tedious work to replace all of them. Besides I want to
find the solution once and forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible work around: Replace all &-s with a "dumb sequence"  (e.g. "###")  before parsing,
and after it's all done replace in the opposite way. (BTW this will work for an HTML containing "true" ampersands,
represented as &amp;

Using this approach the example above turns into the following

```
public static void test() {
   String text="<html>" +
   "<head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\" />" +
   "<title>Testing Escapes with DOM</title>" +
   "</head>" +
   "<body lang=\"en\"><p>This is an escape: &mdash;</p></body>" +
   "</html>";

   try {
       DocumentBuilder builder = 
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
       Document inputDoc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                text.replace("&", "###").getBytes()));

       Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
       ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       transformer.transform(new DOMSource(inputDoc), new StreamResult(baos));

       System.out.println("Result: " + baos.toString().replace("###", "&"));

       } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
       }
 }
```

A very awkward solution and an enormous waste of memory (what a challenge for so poorly implemented Dalvik Garbage Collection engine!), and I will certainly prefer something less patchy...